# Visualizing data for the purpose of data cleaning

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-cleaning

I have a column of a data frame with millions of rows (almost 8 million). I want to investigate this column in order to do some data cleaning. The data contained is trip_distance of NYC's yellow taxis. 
I tried a simple plotting with `sns.distplot()` but it doesn't give me a clear plot.

[image]

I did try to use a range too: `sns.distplot(df['trip_distance']<200, kde=False, bins=10, norm_hist=False)`, but I got this which again does not look helpful:

[image]

Is there a way to understand this column through visualization?

Comment: Can you provide some insight of what do you expect, what is not working and what have you tried? What's the range of the values being plotted for example?

Comment: yes. I will edit my question now.

Comment: Use the `describe` method of your dataframe to get some summary statistics for this column, they will help you decide what is an appropriate visualisation technique to use and may also tell you what cleaning you need to do.

Comment: From your sample plots either your data have too small variance (which is unnatural) or there is some error where they were populated. Check if there is a variance at all (if all have the same value then you have a problem)

Comment: You also have an error for your second plot. `df['trip_distance']<200` will be a list of booleans. You want `df[df['trip_distance'] < 200]`

Comment: Now you've edited your question the problem is clear: the overwhelming majority of cab journeys are only a few miles but there are a very small number of extremely long journeys which results in the first graph. As I said previously, the second graph is plotting a bunch of booleans (will be interpreted as 0s or 1s!)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:->

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s=pd.read_csv("name.csv",usecols=['col_name'],squeeze=True)
s.plot.bar() #for bar graph
s.plot.hist() #for histogram
```